# Removing expired OAuth tokens from database

Tags: dotnetopenauth

After finishing a WCF SOAP webservice which employs DotNetOpenAuth, it occured to me that once a consumertoken is stored in the OAuthConsumer table it is never deleted, not even after the token is considered expired.

I have edited the DotNetOpenAuth project's standard AuthorizedConsumers.aspx page so that users can manually revoke access to an application, basically deleting the consumertoken from the database, but I was wondering if it shouldn't be possible to have old tokens removed automatically. For example, when the user attempts to access the application which the token grants access to, shouldn't there be some sort of check to see if there isn't already a token, and if there is, whether it's expired or not, removing the old token if it *is* expired, before making a new one?

I don't actually know if there are any checks already in place (I did look for them but can't find them), are there? And how would I go about adding code to remove expired tokens from the database? Where exactly would I insert that code? In the StoreNewRequestToken method of the DataBaseTokenManager class?

Thank you!

Comment: Ah, just realized that no, old tokens should not be removed whenever a new one is made. However, we would like to keep the number of rows in the database from getting too high. So, we'd like to remove older tokens nonetheless. Is there some way to do this in code, or should this be done through some sort of event in the mysql database?

Comment: I'm wondering the same thing. Where did you find out about not deleting old tokens? I'm assuming the same in that expired tokens should be deleted. Makes sense to me at least.

Answer (score 0):

Cleaning your database tables is beyond the scope of DotNetOpenAuth. You can implement it however you like. For instance, you might have a database stored procedure that removes token rows that have expired and invoke it on a timer somehow. DotNetOpenAuth expects you to only return valid (non-expired) tokens from your implementation of a token manager interface. The expiration of these tokens is given to you when DNOA first asks you to store them.

As for avoiding your tokens table growing too large, there are a couple of approaches. You can use short-lived tokens and be sure to clean your tables periodically. But the best approach is used in DotNetOpenAuth's OAuth 2 implementation, so if you can switch to OAuth 2 then that's ideal. Once you're there, you'll discover there is no token table at all. The closest thing you have is an Authorizations table, which only has a row for every individual user approval gesture, and you can remove them when (and if) those authorizations ever expire. With that authorization, clients can obtain as many unique tokens as they want and your database never grows because the tokens are self describing and signed. And DNOA manages it all for you.